# Android app included also service

Tags: android

I write app for Android, and it should also be included the service. I want to install  app  at same time install too service.I have tried many forms, but fails.Can  you give me  link, where similar thing will be done, or recommend me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: just add a service class in that particular application and define it in manifest file and define it is in your application that when the service will start.

Comment: but when exit from app service also closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is main class from where the service will be launched.

MainActivity.java

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourService.class);
    startService(intent);

    }
```

YourService.java

```
   public class YourService extends Service {

   @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
   }

   @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // here do code what you want do;

    return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

And if u want to work service after restart service when device will restart
then you should receiver

then define service in Manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".YourService"></service>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a tutorial for services](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

the service can run even if the app is closed

Comment: this is not the answer, i suggest same thing in comment. Actually it is the main work of service that service run in background even the app is closed.